# Trying to change port to 80 on webpack-dev-server gives error

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have this in my package json:

```
webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.config.js --port 80
```

I have also tried adding the port to the config like so:

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  port: '80',
},
```

and it gives the same error:

```
webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.config.js --port 80

loader option has been deprecated - replace with "use"
events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 127.0.0.1:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1057:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1257:19)
    at listen (net.js:1306:10)
    at doListening (net.js:1421:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:62:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:78:10)
```

Any help with something i'm doing wrong appreciated, or with what the error is in relation to. Thanks

Comment: Regular users are not allowed to bind to port 80, ports below 1024 require root/adminstrator rights. That's why these processes are generally using ports like 3000 or 8080. Why do you want to run it on port 80?

Comment: If you're on a Mac, would using sudo help ? 

       sudo webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.config.js --port 80

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## How to fix

You will need to either run as root using sudo, or setup a proxy that redirects requests on port 80 to a port over 1024.

## Why it doesn't work

Regular users cannot listen on ports lower than 1024, so you cannot listen on port 80.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu and have the exact same issue with port 80. After I add "sudo" in front of "npm run dev" the issue disappears.