# How to change port number in vue-cli project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

How to change the Port number in the Vue-CLI project so that it runs on another port instead of 8080.

Comment: On macOS, please remember about this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46813423/13762066

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The port for the Vue-cli webpack template is found in your app root's [`myApp/config/index.js`](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/config/index.js#L17).

All you have to do is modify the `port` value inside the `dev` block:

```
 dev: {
    proxyTable: {},
    env: require('./dev.env'),
    port: 4545,
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    cssSourceMap: false
  }
```

Now you can access your app with `localhost:4545`

also if you have `.env` file better to set it from there

Comment: In the latest vuejs version. The file is no longer used, instead using: <your_project_root>/vue.config.js.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but please mention Vue version.

Comment: do you mean the vue-cli version? vue version has no effect on this

Comment: The file `myApp/config/index.js` does not exist!

Comment: Vue CLI 3 uses vue.config.js at project root. It has to be created manually IIRC.

Comment: there is no vue.config.js there

Comment: sorry, I think with the latest update it has changed, you can update the answer one you figure it out

Comment: `"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 80"
  },`

Comment: Since this is the (un)helpful first listed response you also want to check: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js under some sub section it is shown.

Comment: Also, you can use `npm run serve -- --port 8085`

Answer (score 257):

If you're using `vue-cli` 3.x, you can simply pass the port to the `npm` command like so:

`npm run serve -- --port 3000`

Then visit `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: You saved me precious time, as the first `--` is not written in the doc: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#using-the-binary. I was typing `npm run serve --port 3000` which seems logical to me, but I got errors... Thumbs up!

Comment: That's because the first `--` escapes the parameters given to `npm run serve` and _not_ to `vue-cli-service`. If you edit `package.json` and the `serve` command directly, you enter it as shown in the documentation: `"serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 3000",`

Comment: While this answer is good and has most up-votes (mine too ;)), I prefer `package.json` change in order not to have to give port to command every time but have it persistent and automatic in `npm run serve` command.

Answer (score 161):

Late to the party, but I think it's helpful to consolidate all these answers into one outlining all options.

Separated in Vue CLI v2 (webpack template) and Vue CLI v3, ordered by precedence (high to low).

## Vue CLI v3

- `package.json`: Add port option to `serve` script: `scripts.serve=vue-cli-service serve --port 4000`
- CLI Option `--port` to `npm run serve`, e.g. `npm run serve -- --port 3000`. Note the `--`, this makes passes the port option to the npm script instead of to npm itself. Since at least v3.4.1, it should be e.g. `vue-cli-service serve --port 3000`.
- Environment Variable `$PORT`, e.g. `PORT=3000 npm run serve`
- `.env` Files, more specific envs override less specific ones, e.g. `PORT=3242`
- `vue.config.js`, `devServer.port`, e.g. `devServer: { port: 9999 }`

References:

- https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver
- https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js
- https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html

## Vue CLI v2 (deprecated)

- Environment Variable `$PORT`, e.g. `PORT=3000 npm run dev`
- `/config/index.js`: `dev.port`

References:

- http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/
- https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/build/webpack.dev.conf.js#L35

Comment: Looks like this changed a tad in latest vue cli (using 3.4.1), here's my "serve" line in package.json: `"serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 4000",`. Works great!

Comment: @RoccoB Thanks, I verified it and added it to the answer.

Comment: The answers above don't seem to work in v3 at this date. I tried the .env option, package.json, vue.config.js, and CLI command option but they all get ignored. The config file docs say "Some values like `host`, `port` and `https` may be overwritten by command line flags." https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver Am I missing something? Anybody else having issues?

Comment: @Ryan - This was reported yesterday in the VueJS CLI Repository Issues: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4452

It is saying to install portfinder (https://github.com/http-party/node-portfinder/) as there was a breaking change which happened with that.

Comment: @RoccoB this has done the trick in my case also. Thanks wwerner for the respose.

Answer (score 51):

As the time of this answer's writing (May 5th 2018), `vue-cli` has its configuration hosted at `<your_project_root>/vue.config.js`. To change the port, see below:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  devServer: {
    open: process.platform === 'darwin',
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 8080, // CHANGE YOUR PORT HERE!
    https: false,
    hotOnly: false,
  },
  // ...
}
```

Full `vue.config.js` reference can be found here: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config

Note that as stated in the docs, “All options for webpack-dev-server” (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) is available within the `devServer` section.

Answer (score 25):

Another option if you're using vue cli 3 is to use a config file. Make a `vue.config.js` at the same level as your `package.json` and put a config like so:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 3000
  }
}
```

Configuring it with the script:

```
npm run serve --port 3000
```

works great but if you have more config options I like doing it in a config file. You can find more info in the [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js).

Comment: I like this answer as it shows that vue.config.js can be used to just change the port and leave everything else as-is which is what was asked originally.

Answer (score 24):

Best way is to update the serve script command in your `package.json` file. Just append `--port 3000` like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 3000",
  "build": "vue-cli-service build",
  "inspect": "vue-cli-service inspect",
  "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
},
```

Answer (score 24):

***First Option:***

OPEN **package.json** and add **"--port port-no"** in **"serve"** section.

Just like below, I have done it.

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 8090",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
}
```

***Second Option***: If You want through command prompt

`npm run serve --port 8090`

Answer (score 17):

If you want to change the localhost port, you can change scripts tag in *package.json*:

```
 "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 3000",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

Answer (score 10):

In the `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  ......
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 8081,   // you can change the port there
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  ......
}
```

You can change the port in the `module.exports` -> `devServer` -> `port`.

Then you restrat the `npm run dev`. You can get that.

Answer (score 9):

Oh my God! It is not that much complicated, with these answers which also works. However, other answers tho this question also works well.

If you really want to use the `vue-cli-service` and if you want to have the port setting in your `package.json` file, which your 'vue create <app-name>' command basically creates, you can use the following configuration: `--port 3000`. So the whole configuration of your script would be like this:

```
...
"scripts": {
"serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 3000",
"build": "vue-cli-service build",
"lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
},
...
```

I am using `@vue/cli 4.3.1 (vue --version)` on a macOS device.

I have also added the vue-cli-service reference:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html

Comment: This answer duplicates one on this page from 3 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60727863/401467

Answer (score 8):

If you use **`yarn`**:

```
yarn serve --port 3000
```

Answer (score 8):

1. open `package.json`
2. add script named `serve`, `"serve": "Vue-cli-service serve --port 8081"`
3. `npm run serve`
   you will server run 8081

```json
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 8081", 
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative approach with `vue-cli` version 3 is to add a `.env` file in the root project directory (along side `package.json`) with the contents:

`PORT=3000`

Running `npm run serve` will now indicate the app is running on port 3000.

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot of answers here varying by version, so I thought I'd confirm and expound upon Julien Le Coupanec's answer above from October 2018 **when using the Vue CLI**. In the most recent version of Vue.js as of this post - **vue@2.6.10** - the outlined steps below made the most sense to me after looking through some of the myriad answers in this post. The [Vue.js documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#using-the-binary) references pieces of this puzzle, but isn't quite as explicit.

1. Open the `package.json` file in the root directory of the Vue.js project.
2. Search for "port" in the `package.json` file.
3. Upon finding the following reference to "port", edit the `serve` script element to reflect the desired port, using the same syntax as shown below:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 8000",
     "build": "vue-cli-service build",
     "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
   }
   ```
4. Make sure to re-start the `npm` server to avoid unnecessary insanity.

The documentation shows that one can effectively get the same result by adding `--port 8080` to the end of the `npm run serve` command like so: `npm run serve --port 8080`. I preferred editing the `package.json` directly to avoid extra typing, but editing `npm run serve --port 1234` inline may come in handy for some.

Answer (score 5):

To change the port (NPM), go to `package.json`. In `scripts` write your own script, for example:

```
"start": "npm run serve --port [PORT YOU WANT]"
```

After that you can start with `npm start`

[image: "scripts":{"start":"npm run serve --- --port 3000"}]

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better. Also, provide a basic coverage of the content of your link, in case it stops working in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Add the `PORT` envvariable to your `serve` script in `package.json`:

```
"serve": "PORT=4767 vue-cli-service serve",
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the port number temporarily, you can add a –port option to npm run serve command.

npm run serve -- --port 6058

Answer (score 2):

You should be good with this:

"serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 8081",

Answer (score 1):

In my vue project in visual studio code, I had to set this in **/config/index.js**. 
Change it in the:

```
module.exports = {
    dev: {
          // Paths
          assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
          assetsPublicPath: '/',
          proxyTable: {},

          host: 'localhost', // can be overwritten by process.env.HOST
          port: 8090, // can be overwritten by process.env.PORT, if port is in use, a free one will be determined
          autoOpenBrowser: false,
          errorOverlay: true,
          notifyOnErrors: true,
          poll: false    
         }
}
```

Comment: I almost did the same. My file's name is 'vue.config.js' and is located at the root of the vue project. The demanded port is found on path module.exports.dev.port. Here it is set to 8090. The other key-value-pairs are not necessary (for me). That's for starting with 'npm run serve' on development mode!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this via Visual Studio Community or Professional (maybe with a .Net Core project) you will find that no matter what steps you do, when you launch the solution that it uses 8080.

Well there is `launch.json` file you need to edit hidden in the `.vscode` directory.
MS don't tell you about this at all and a file search does not seem to find it.

Answer (score -2):

Go to node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/options.js 
At the bottom inside the "devServer" unblock the codes 
Now give your desired port number in the "port" :)

```
devServer: {
   open: process.platform === 'darwin',
   host: '0.0.0.0',
   port: 3000,  // default port 8080
   https: false,
   hotOnly: false,
   proxy: null, // string | Object
   before: app => {}
}
```

Comment: go to node_modules/@vue/cli-service ... ? Doesn't that get overwritten on npm update?

Comment: you don't want to make code edits - should be configurable