# Vue js 2.5.16 automatically picks up a port

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Vue.js Automatically picks up a new port every time a dev build is being created.Whenever i try to run `npm run dev` it automatically selects a port on its own instead of the one mentioned in `config/index.js`

> port: 8080, // can be overwritten by process.env.PORT, if port is in
>   use, a free one will be determined

I understand the comment mentioned here,but when i tried to change port in `build/webpack.dev.conf.js` too

```
devServer: {
    clientLogLevel: 'warning',
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [
        { from: /.*/, to: path.posix.join(config.dev.assetsPublicPath, 'index.html') },
      ],
    },
    hot: true,
    contentBase: false, // since we use CopyWebpackPlugin.
    compress: true,
    host: HOST || config.dev.host,
    // port: PORT || config.dev.port,
    port: 8080,
    open: config.dev.autoOpenBrowser,
    overlay: config.dev.errorOverlay
      ? { warnings: false, errors: true }
      : false,
    publicPath: config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
    proxy: config.dev.proxyTable,
    quiet: true, // necessary for FriendlyErrorsPlugin
    watchOptions: {
      poll: config.dev.poll,
    }
  },
```

seems not to work as well.I want my vue app to be listened on only one port that i mention,any help regarding this issue would be really appreciated.

I already have seen this question but this doesn't solve my problem.
[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219819/how-to-change-port-number-in-vue-cli-project/50189858)

Comment: Check if the port is already in use `sudo netstat -lpn |grep :'8080'`

Comment: Thank you @Helpinghand you can add this text in answer.I was not killing the `npm run dev` process in a right way.I was using `ctrl+x` on ubuntu instead of using `ctrl+c`.

Comment: I killed the existing running process on 8080 using this command `fuser -n tcp -k 8080` now my server is being listened on 8080

Comment: Just added it as answer, kill -9 <PID no.> can also be used to kill the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue is picking up a new port automatically, because it finds the current port as busy. You can check if the port is already in use or not, if yes then do the following:

Find if port (here '8080') is in use:

```
sudo netstat -lpn |grep :'8080'
```

Kill the process:

```
kill -9 <PID>
```