# How to change vue-cli message after successfull compile ("App running at...")?

Tags: vue-cli

I use vue-cli in my dockerized project, where port mapping looks like this: "4180:8080", and the actual message after compiling my SPA looks like:

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/app/ 

  It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container.
  Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container's external mapped port>/app/
```

App works fine, I could access at via http://localhost:4180/app/ as conceived, but I'm not able to find a proper way to change the message above to show this link instead of "It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container...". I could use webpack hooks to insert link before the message but actually wanna find the way to change the message, generated by cli. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to this question - as I was looking to do the same thing with bash, running inside a Docker container (possibly what you're already doing).

You could achieve this by invoking Vue CLI commands through spawning a child node process, from within your Docker container (assuming your container is running node). You can then modify the output of `stdout` and `stderr` accordingly.

You can call a Javascript file in one of two ways:

- use a shell script (bash, for example) to call node and run this script
- set the entrypoint of your Dockerfile to use this script (assuming you're running node by default)

```
// index.js

const { spawn } = require('child_process')

const replacePort = string => {
  return string.replace(`<your container's external mapped port>`, 8000)
}

const vueCLI = (appLocation, args) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const vue = spawn('vue', args, {cwd: appLocation})

    vue.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(replacePort(data.toString('utf8', 0, data.length)))
    })

    vue.stderr.on('data', (error) => {
      console.log(replacePort(error.toString('utf8', 0, error.length)))
    })

    vue.on('close', (exitCode) => {
      if (exitCode === 0) {
        resolve()
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Vue CLI exited with a non-zero exit code'))
      }
    })
  })
}

vueCLI('path/to/app', CLI_Options).then(() => resolve()).catch(error => console.error(error))
```

This approach does have drawbacks, not limited to:

- performance being slower - due to this being less efficient
- potential danger of memory leaks, subject to implementation
- risk of zombies, should the parent process die

For the reasons above and several others, this is a route that was found to be unsuitable in my specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the message, [it's better to change the port Vue is listening on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51343026/1542723).

> .    npm run serve -- --port 4180

This automatically updates your message to say the new port, and after you updated your docker port forward for the new port, it it will work again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a suitable option. The external port in my project could be changed in the future. I need to stay my Dockerfile as constant as possible and do not edit it anytime when my team members could require another port. I injected information about port mapping to my environment variables and use it, for example, to generate links in messages of my sandbox server (express&nodejs), so I'm trying to inject this info to CLI messages. I already described one way to achieve a similar effect in my question but hoped there is more elegant.