# Can I change the default port from 8080 to something else in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, port

I have been working on Vue.js and Node.js to build my app. When I have started with Vue it is by default running on 8080 and Node I am running on 3008.

What I am trying to do is due to some circumstances I want to change the port for Vue from 8080 to any other like 8086 or 3005. How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219819/how-to-change-port-number-in-vue-cli-project

Comment: @Helpinghand I already read that there is no such file in my project

Comment: What cli or from where did you get starting vue project?

Answer (score 15):

Simply you can run the following command to run vue app as per your required port :

> npm run serve --port 8086

Another way is to update the serve script command in your `package.json` file. Just append `--port 8086` like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 8086",
  "build": "vue-cli-service build",
  "inspect": "vue-cli-service inspect",
  "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the way! ...that worked for me!

```
npm run serve -- --port 8086
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used run  `npm run serve --port 8081`, but it ends up with error message `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type number (8081)`.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have one create `vue.config.js` in the root dir of your project and there add this option:

```
module.exports = {
   devServer: {
      port: 8086
   }
}
```

In [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver) you can see all the available options for configuring the dev server.

Check also [vue-cli docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-loaderoptions).

Answer (score 1):

With `npm`:

```
npm run serve --port 8086
```

With `yarn`:

```
yarn serve --port 8086
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) as your build tool, you can override the default port with the one you want by providing a [server.port](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-port) entry in the vite configuration file - `vite.config.js`

In the example below, I set the default port to `8086`

```
export default defineConfig({
  ...

  server: {
    port: 8086,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  ...
  devServer: {
    port: 8086,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

VueJS 2 with `npm` (you can do either):

```
npm run serve --port=8086
npm run serve --port=3005
```

VueJS 2 with `yarn` (you can do either):

```
yarn serve --port=8086
yarn serve --port=3005
```

VueJS 3 with `npm` (you can do either):

```
npm run dev --port=8086
npm run dev --port=3005
```

VueJS 3 with `yarn` (you can do either):

```
npm run serve --port=8086
npm run serve --port=3005
```

You can also do the other answers, like changing the ports in `vue.config.js`

Please note that if port `8080` was occupied when you first started the VueJS app, there is an app that uses it and the initial remedy is to restart your Laptop/PC.

Answer (score -4):

DIR: node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\commands
CHANGE FILE: serve.js

const defaults = {
host: '0.0.0.0',
port: 8086,
https: false
}

Comment: You should never change anything directly in `node_modules`